# jquery photo gallery next-prev button binding problem

Tags: jquery, indexing, photo-gallery

I'm using this photo gallery with this:

```
$('.normsize img:gt(0)').hide();
$('.photos a').click(function(){
    var index = $('.photos a').index(this);
    $('.normsize img:visible').hide();
    $('.normsize img:eq('+index+')').fadeIn();
});
```

with thumbnails in a div and the normal size pics next to it.

My question is: How would I bind the next and previous buttons . Its probably simpler than what I m using already.

**Edit:** Fixed code output.

Comment: I would but I can't post images supposedly.well Its just images in a div  (thumbnails) and the next div is the normal sized pics.

Comment: I didnt post my whole Jquery code since Its just css stuff not related to the index.

Comment: I just dont know how to formulate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the current image index in a global variable.

```
var currentIndex = 0;
var lastIndex = $('.normsize img').size() - 1;

function showPic(index) {
    $('.normsize img:visible').hide();
    $('.normsize img:eq('+index+')').fadeIn();
    currentIndex = index;
}

$('.photos a').click(function() {
    showPic($('.photos a').index(this));
});

$('#next').click(function() {
    // If is the last go to first, else go to next
    showPic(currentIndex == lastIndex ? 0 : currentIndex + 1);
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
    // If is the first, go to last, else go to previous
    showPic(currentIndex == 0 ? lastIndex : currentIndex - 1);
});

$('.normsize img').hide(); // Hide all
showPic(0); // Initialize first picture shown
```

Comment: It works really well except that now I m stuck with another problem.When I go into the next gallery which is hidden when the first  one is visible, the next and prev buttons follow the index of the first gallery,how do I make it follow the index of this second gallery?

Comment: I realize I should've used the src attribute to switch between the thumbnails and the normal-sized images. Having to hide all the following galleries sounds like a newbie way to do things to me.Is it?

Comment: you can store the image urls in an array, or you can just hide/show img elements, it's up to you. when you go to the second gallery just reset the currentIndex variable

Comment: Last question..How would I reset the index of the currentIndex variable?

Comment: I finally made my photo galleries work the way I wanted thanks to you. I had a hard time though as a newbie. I learned that i had to unbind the click for each gallery and I did the index resetting and it works.I had to try a couple different things but it works now.The client is going to be happy. I think its more satisfying than using a plugin. I did that a couple of times. Grab a lightbox,copy the code but you don't learn anything that way.I m reading that book "from novice to ninja' and its the best Jquery book that Ive read yet.